# Downgrade from Visual Studio-2012 to Visual Studio-2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a project in Visual Studio 2012 and I want to open it in Microsoft Visual Studios 2010. Is there any way to convert from Visual Studio-2012 to Visual Studio-2010 or Do I have to create a new project in 2010 and add all files from 2012 project?

Comment: According to this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486776/visual-studio-2010-cannot-open-a-2010-solution-that-visual-studio-2012-modified?rq=1), you need VS2010 SP1 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use .net 4.0, open the sln file and replace this code

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
```

at beginning of the sln with

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

Now open the sln in Visual Studio 2010.

If you used .net 4.5.x in VS2012 you are out of luck, because VS2010 only supports .net 4.0.